# Number format in PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to display price in my front page. But the format of the number required is,

- Entered price: 10000 Display: 10,000
- Entered price: 10000.10 Display: 10,000.1
- Entered price: 10000.01 Display: 10,000.01

if I am using the following code

```
echo  number_format ($price,2,'.',',');
```

But through this the result is displayed in this manner.
**Entered price: 10000 Display: 10,000.00**

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

There's a function in PHP called `money_format()`.

Have a look at it on http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: how does money_format help with this? It doesnt account for variable decimals either. still have to input how many you want into the format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, from a clarity and consistency point of view, having 2 digits after the decimal point makes more sense especially when showing prices.

@barryhunter made a valid point and the following doesn't work.

```
echo rtrim(number_format($price,2,'.',','),'0.');
```

However, this does:

```
trim(trim(number_format($price,2,'.',','),'0'),'.');
```

Look:

```
<?php
$a=array('10000.00','10000.10','10000.01');

foreach ($a as $price)
{
    echo $price.' - '.rtrim(rtrim(number_format($price,2,'.',','),'0'),'.')."\n";
}
?>

$> php -f t.php
10000.00 - 10,000
10000.10 - 10,000.1
10000.01 - 10,000.01
```

Comment: That wont work, will strip the ending zeros in the actual number, so when $price=10000; it will output "10," not what wanted!

Comment: @barryhunter - Good point. My apologies. IGNORE MY ANSWER. IT NO WORK!

Comment: OK. I had another think and sorted out my earlier answer. Kudos to @barryhunter - thank you!

Comment: @daveyBoy. This will not help

Comment: @user1179868 - how does it not help? It will format the example numbers that you gave in the format that you requested - strip away trailing 0's and decimal point in currency. What exactly are you after?

Answer (score 1):

You have set number of decimial points to 2 so that is why you have 10,000.00. Try to user in this way:

```
echo  number_format ($price,1,'.',',');
```

And also it is better to use [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) if you are working with money values.

Comment: The OP wants 2 decimal points for `10,000.01` and 1 decimal point for `10,000.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do

```
echo number_format($price,floor($price)==$price?0:2,'.',',');
```

displaying a price as  10,000.1 just looks odd to me.

But if you really must

```
$bits = explode('.',$price);
echo number_format($price,strlen($bits[1]),'.',',');
```

(edit) In reply to the comment, it works for me...

```
<?php
$a=array(10000.00,10000.10,10000.01);

foreach ($a as $price)
{
    $bits = explode('.',$price);
    echo $price.' - '.number_format($price,strlen($bits[1]),'.',',')."\n";
}
?>

$ php t.php
10000 - 10,000
10000.1 - 10,000.1
10000.01 - 10,000.01
```

Comment: burryhunter. Thanks for your reply. but unfortunately it does not work for 10000.01 or 10000.1